# In ios 9 - force user to login again after a certain period of time

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to force my users to login again if they haven't used my app for a certain period of time - my mobile bank app does this.  How would I go about doing this in IOS 9 and swift?

[ Edited Jan 3, 2016 - Sorry if the above was poorly phrased and for the delay in rewording the question (Christmas holidays etc).  Here goes:

My app gets data from a server and I would like to know if the user has been away from my app for a certain period of time - because the data may be out of date - and if this is the case I would like to redirect the user to login again so I can refresh the data on his/her device.

I can timestamp each login and was just wondering how to tell if the app has 'been reawakened' (in a nutshell, my question is: how do I do this?) and if I can do this then I will check the elapsed time from last login and redirect the user to login again if necessary.

I hope this makes more sense this time.]

Thanks again.

Comment: Just periodically check if the login date time interval since now is greater than n seconds.

Comment: Just store the date of the last login in your user defaults. Then when launching the application check if this date is more than two hours whatever ago and if so, ask to login again and store the current date in the user defaults (to get the current date just use `NSDate()`).

Comment: Ok, so I know the elapsed time since last login, now how do I force the login page to be displayed since the app will, by default, re-open at the last page the user was looking at before he/she drifted off? (Maybe I'm missing something.)

Comment: In the appDidEnterForeground: or appDidBecomeActive: methods check if too much time has elapsed and, if so, segue to the login view controller.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot!  Sorry for the delay in getting back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: Upon login, save the current date (`NSDate()`) [save it e.g. in the userDefaults.]

Then In the `applicationDidBecomeActive:` method check if too much time has elapsed since the saved login date and now.
=> if the delta of seconds is too great, it is time to force a re-login. e.g. p=by pushing the login view controller or by performing the segue to the login view controller.

Answer (score 1):

Usually your server will give your application an encrypted token when you log in. That encrypted token is then passed with every request. The server can then invalidate the token after some time, or invalidate it if something else happens (for example, if a user's device is stolen, they should be able to log out from any other device).

Security isn't something that you should handle in the application; it should be done server side. The only thing your application needs to do is to request a username and password again from the user and then request a token from the server, whenever the app is started without having a token, or if a token is rejected.

Comment: Ah! I was expecting a userID from the server on successful login and store it in userDefaults - then make my requests using the userID.  If after the app  is 'awakened' from sleep and the elapsed time is greater than (say) an hour from last login - then the user has to login again. Sounds like I must be on the wrong track then?